# TextField inside StreamBuilder lost the edited values

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-layout

I am developing user profile update page for a app, I got problem there, To populate form with initial data I have used `StreamBuilder` and used `TextEditingController` load data to `TextField`, data loading fine and works well, but problem is when I try to change `TextField` and focus to next `TextField` `StreamBuilder` refresh the ui with tha data which load previously and lost edited data. In this case Stream does not updated from network call. Anybody came across this situation ? or any recommended way to do this?. Please help.

Code

```
class UserProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserProfileScreenState createState() => _UserProfileScreenState();
}

class _UserProfileScreenState extends State<UserProfileScreen> {
  UserProfileBloc userBloc;

  final firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  final surnameNameController = TextEditingController();
  final phoneController = TextEditingController();
  final emailController = TextEditingController();

  var _hashCode = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userBloc = UserProfileBloc();
    userBloc.getUser();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    userBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.close,
            color: ColorPallet.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          },
        )
      ),
      body: buildUserProfileContent(context),
    );
  }

  Container buildUserProfileContent(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<UserProfileState>(
        stream: userBloc.user,
        initialData: UserProfileInitState(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data is UserProfileDataState) {
            UserProfileDataState state = snapshot.data;
            return buildProfileContent(state.user, state.profileImage);
          }

        },
      ),
    );
    //);
  }

  ListView buildProfileContent(User user, Uint8List profileImage) {
    firstNameController.text = user.firstName;
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: firstNameController,
              ),
            ]

        ),
        )],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs as you are setting the values in build method. If you want to set values as you are doing above, in the class `_UserProfileScreenState` maintain a variable `_initialized = false` and make it `true` after initializing.

Something like:

```
if(!_initialized){
    firstNameController.text = user.firstName;
    _initialized = true;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use onChange follow mycode.

```
  onChanged: (value) => {_onChangeValue()},

  StreamBuilder(
                        initialData: true,
                        stream: _loginBloc.isToggledPass,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          return TextField(
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            obscureText: snapshot.data,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                            onChanged: (value) => {_onChangeValue()},
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: hintPassword,
                          );
                        }),
```